# Wxpython: Couldn't retrieve information about list control item XXX

Tags: python, wxpython

When deleting select item, ErrorMsg poped up: "can't retrieve information about list control item XXX".
Can anyone take a look and find a way to solve it?
Appreciate your help!

> import wx
>
> ```
> DATA = {
> 0 : (u"Test2", "123456", ),
> 1 : (u"Test", "123456",),
> 2 : (u"doe", "156789", ),
> 3 : (u"John", "13455", )
> }
>
>
> class MyApp(wx.App):
>
>     def OnInit(self):
>         frame = MyFrame(None)
>         frame.Show()
>         self.SetTopWindow(frame)
>         return True
>
>
> class MyFrame(wx.Frame):
>
>     def __init__(self, parent):
>         wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, wx.NewId(), size=(500, -1))
>         wx.Frame.CenterOnScreen(self)
>         self.panel = MyPanel(self)
>
>
> class MyPanel(wx.Panel):
>
>     def __init__(self, parent):
>         wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent)
>         self.list = MyListCtrl(self,3)
>         self.add_button = wx.Button(self, label="add")
>         h_sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
>         h_sizer.Add(self.add_button, proportion=1, flag=wx.ALL, border=5)
>         v_sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
>         v_sizer.Add(h_sizer, proportion=0, flag=wx.EXPAND)
>         v_sizer.Add(self.list, proportion=1, flag=wx.EXPAND, border=5)
>         self.SetSizer(v_sizer)
>         self.add_button.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON,self.onAdd)
>
>     def onAdd(self, event):
>         self.new_w = NewWindow(self)
>         self.new_w.Show()
>
>
> class MyPopupMenu(wx.Menu):
>
>     def __init__(self,parent, item):
>         super(MyPopupMenu,self).__init__()
>         self.parent = parent
>         self.item = item
>         menuEdit = wx.MenuItem(self,wx.NewId(), 'edit %s' % item[0])
>         self.AppendItem(menuEdit)
>         self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.onEdit, menuEdit)
>         menuDel = wx.MenuItem(self,wx.NewId(), 'delete %s' % item[0])
>         self.AppendItem(menuDel)
>         self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.OnDelete, menuDel)
>
>     def onEdit(self,e):
>         self.parent.parent.edit_w = NewWindow(self.parent.parent)
>         self.parent.parent.edit_w.Show()
>
>     def OnDelete(self,e):
>         self.parent.DeleteAllItems()
>
> class MyListCtrl(wx.ListCtrl):
>     def __init__(self, parent, columns):
>         wx.ListCtrl.__init__(self, parent, style=wx.LC_REPORT)
>         self.parent = parent
>         self.R_MOUSE = 0
>         self.InsertColumn(0, "name")
>         self.InsertColumn(1, "phone")
>         self.InsertColumn(2, "address")
>         self.SetColumnWidth(0, 200)
>         self.Bind(wx.EVT_LIST_ITEM_SELECTED, self.OnSelect)
>         self.Bind(wx.EVT_RIGHT_DOWN, self.OnRightDown)
>         self.itemDataMap = {}
>         self.refresh_list()
>
>
>     def refresh_list(self):
>         self.DeleteAllItems()
>         for entry in DATA.items():
>             self.Append(entry[1])
>             self.SetItemData(entry[0],entry[0])
>
>     def OnRightDown(self, event):
>         self.R_MOUSE = 1
>         self.position = event.GetPosition()
>         event.Skip()
>
>     def OnSelect(self, event):
>         index = event.GetIndex()
>         item = []
>         for i in range(3):
>             item.append(self.GetItem(itemId=index, col=i).GetText())
>         self.SetItemState(index, 0, wx.LIST_STATE_SELECTED)
>         self.SetItemBackgroundColour(index, wx.Colour(255,255,0))
>         if self.R_MOUSE:
>             self.R_MOUSE = 0
>             self.PopupMenu(MyPopupMenu(self, item), self.position)
>
>
> class NewWindow(wx.Frame):
>
>     def __init__(self, parent):
>         wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, size=(400,250), style=wx.DEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE)
>         self.parent = parent
>         self.CenterOnParent()
>         panel = wx.Panel(self)
>
>
>     def onClick(self,event):
>         self.Close()
>
>
> if __name__ == "__main__":
>     app = MyApp()
>     app.MainLoop()
> ```
>
> ----------------------------------**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should popup the menu in another event handler for **EVT_LIST_ITEM_RIGHT_CLICK**
Try following code:

```
import wx

DATA = {
    0 : (u"Test2", "123456", ),
    1 : (u"Test", "123456",),
    2 : (u"doe", "156789", ),
    3 : (u"John", "13455", )
}

class MyApp(wx.App):

    def OnInit(self):
        frame = MyFrame(None)
        frame.Show()
        self.SetTopWindow(frame)
        return True


class MyFrame(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, wx.NewId(), size=(500, -1))
        wx.Frame.CenterOnScreen(self)
        self.panel = MyPanel(self)


class MyPanel(wx.Panel):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent)
        self.list = MyListCtrl(self,3)
        self.add_button = wx.Button(self, label="add")
        h_sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        h_sizer.Add(self.add_button, proportion=1, flag=wx.ALL, border=5)
        v_sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        v_sizer.Add(h_sizer, proportion=0, flag=wx.EXPAND)
        v_sizer.Add(self.list, proportion=1, flag=wx.EXPAND, border=5)
        self.SetSizer(v_sizer)
        self.add_button.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON,self.onAdd)

    def onAdd(self, event):
        self.new_w = NewWindow(self)
        self.new_w.Show()


class MyPopupMenu(wx.Menu):

    def __init__(self,parent, item):
        super(MyPopupMenu,self).__init__()
        self.parent = parent
        self.item = item
        menuEdit = wx.MenuItem(self,wx.NewId(), 'edit %s' % item.GetText())
        self.AppendItem(menuEdit)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.onEdit, menuEdit)
        menuDel = wx.MenuItem(self,wx.NewId(), 'delete %s' % item.GetText())
        self.AppendItem(menuDel)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.OnDelete, menuDel)

    def onEdit(self,e):
        self.parent.parent.edit_w = NewWindow(self.parent.parent)
        self.parent.parent.edit_w.Show()

    def OnDelete(self,e):
        self.parent.DeleteAllItems()


class MyListCtrl(wx.ListCtrl):
    def __init__(self, parent, columns):
        wx.ListCtrl.__init__(self, parent, style=wx.LC_REPORT)
        self.parent = parent
        self.R_MOUSE = 0
        self.InsertColumn(0, "name")
        self.InsertColumn(1, "phone")
        self.InsertColumn(2, "address")
        self.SetColumnWidth(0, 200)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_LIST_ITEM_SELECTED, self.OnSelect)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_LIST_ITEM_RIGHT_CLICK, self.onRightClick)

        self.itemDataMap = {}
        self.refresh_list()

    def onRightClick(self,evt):
        pos = evt.GetPosition()
        self.PopupMenu(MyPopupMenu(self, self.itemSel), pos)

    def refresh_list(self):
        self.DeleteAllItems()
        for entry in DATA.items():
            self.Append(entry[1])
            self.SetItemData(entry[0],entry[0])

    def OnSelect(self, event):
        index = event.GetIndex()
        self.itemSel = self.GetItem(itemId=index)

class NewWindow(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, size=(400,250), style=wx.DEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE)
        self.parent = parent
        self.CenterOnParent()
        panel = wx.Panel(self)

    def onClick(self,event):
        self.Close()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = MyApp()
    app.MainLoop()
```